# Initialize dataframe without column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this.

```
             state sex salary
jordan        CA    m    100
lebron        NY    m    200
```

There are 4 columns however the first one does not have a column name. The other 3 columns are `state` , `sex,` salary`.  How do i initialize a data frame withe the above data?

I tried the following.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['jordan','CA','m',100], ['lebron','NY','m',200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['','state','sex','Age'])
```

When i do `df.columns` I see

`Index(['', 'state', 'sex', 'Age'], dtype='object')`

However I **expect** to see `Index(['state', 'sex', 'Age'], dtype='object')` when i do `df.columns`

So i am wondering how can i initialize the dataframe such that the column that has the names `jordan` and `lebron` is not actually a column.

Comment: set it as index using `df.set_index` or much better while building the `df` use `pd.DataFrame(data_wthout_jordan_and_lebron, index= ['jordan', 'lebron'], columns= your_cols)`?

Comment: @Ch3steR can you please show example? I am also asking so i learn the proper/pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
data = [['CA','m',100], ['NY','m',200]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['state','sex','Age'], index=['jordan', 'lebron'])
```

or you can do with your existing datafram as below

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [['jordan','CA','m',100], ['lebron','NY','m',200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['','state','sex','Age']) 

df.set_index(df[''],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=[''], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add the scenario when loading from csv file, you can use `index_col` to specify which column to use as index.

Assumes the data is in a file named `temp.csv` like:

```
,state,sex,salary
jordan,CA,m,100
lebron,NY,m,200
```

you can read in the data with:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv", index_col=0)
```

then you can get

```py
df.index # Index(['jordan', 'lebron'], dtype='object')
df.columns # Index(['state', 'sex', 'salary'], dtype='object')
```

Reference:

- `DataFrame`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html
- `read_csv`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html